# Grails Wrapper: run/re-run before or after change version?

Tags: grails, build, versioning

I tried looking for the answer for this [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/wrapper.html) but couldn't find it. If this *is* documented somewhere, please send the link as a comment and I'll delete the question.

I can't figure out the proper order for using Grails Wrapper when upgrading an app version:

1. Do I run `grails wrapper` and *then* change `application.properties` to the new version of Grails, and *then* execute all future commands using `grailsw`?; or
2. Do I change `application.properties` to the new version, then run `grails wrapper`, and *then* run all future commands with `grailsw`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `grails wrapper` will download the version of the wrapper specified in `application.properties`, so you should run it after changing the version.